# Find the empty sections

Tags: macros

Is there a way to hind the sections without content ? I would like to hide sections with empty content without modifying the counter of sections. This is for making a short version of a lesson only showing important results without breaking the full lesson structure.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\section{With content}

Bla, bla, ...

\section{No content}

\section{With content}

Bla, bla, ...

\section{With content}

Bla, bla, ...

\section{No content}

\section{With content}

Bla, bla, ...

\end{document}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "find" You can probably make a section heading detect that the previous thing was a heading, but depending what you want to do with that information that may or may not be useful. Finding such things in an editor is of course also possible (and possibly more useful)

Comment: Do you want to just signal the user that the section is empty (through a warning message, for example), or do you want to make the section command do nothing ig the previous section was empty?

Comment: I have updated my question. I "just" want to hide sections with empty content without modifying the counter of sections.

Comment: as I suspected that makes things harder, you could make `\section` detect that it is following a previous `\section` but by then you have already typeset the "no content" heading and you can't go back.

Comment: This sis not a big problem because I can use the aux file and do the job during a second compilation. How can I do the detection ?

Comment: I had in mind detecting the flags that latex uses to suppress indentation of the first paragraph, to detect one heading coming after another but I posted an answer that instead looks ahead so can do it in one pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right, then this slight variation of David Carlisle's answer also allows the starred variant and the optional argument before the non-optional argument. But I give no warranties/guarantees of any kind. Maybe I overlook something. If so, please drop a hint.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\makeatletter
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
%%.............................................................................
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \@secondoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo{ }{}\@firstoftwo}%
}
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\@ifdefinable\zzsection{\let\zzsection\section}%
% !!!! It is assumed that \section has the following syntax:
% !!!! \section<optional star><optional argument in square brackets><non-optional argument>
\DeclareRobustCommand\section{%
  \kernel@ifnextchar*{\@firstoftwo{\mysection{*}}}{\mysection{}}%
}%
\newcommand\mysection[1]{%
  \kernel@ifnextchar[{\mysection@opt{#1}}{\mysection@noopt{#1}}%
}%
\@ifdefinable\mysection@opt{%
  \long\def\mysection@opt#1[#2]#3{\mychecknextsection{#1}{#1[{#2}]{#3}}}%
}%
\@ifdefinable\mysection@noopt{%
  \long\def\mysection@noopt#1#2{\mychecknextsection{#1}{#1{#2}}}%
}%
\newcommand\mychecknextsection[2]{%
  % #1 star or emptiness; #2 arguments of the section-command.
  \kernel@ifnextchar{\section}%
              {% use token-register \toks@ for avoiding expansion of the things that get typed out.
                \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{%
                  \expandafter\toks@\expandafter{\the\toks@}%
                }{%
                  \toks@{zap \section#2}%
                  \typeout{\the\toks@}%
                }%
                \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{\refstepcounter{section}}{}%
              }%
              {\kernel@ifnextchar{\par}{\zzparsection\section#2}{\zzsection#2}}%
}%
\@ifdefinable\zzparsection{\long\def\zzparsection#1\par{#1}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{With content}

Bla, bla, ...

\section*{No content}

\section{No content}

\section*{Some content}

Bla

\section*{No content}

% E.g., this one would have broken things in the version before the edit:    
\section[No \textit{content} in contents]{No content}

\section*{No content}

\section{With content}

Bla, bla, ...

\section{With content}

Bla, bla, ...

\section{No content}

\section{With content}

Bla, bla, ...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course with things like

```
\section{No content}

\relax

\section{Content}
```

or

```
\begingroup
% whatsoever
\section{No content}
\endgroup

\section{Content}
```

both sections will be treated like sections with content.

Comment: Thanks for this completed solution.

Comment: Un acceptés answer.

Comment: @projetmbc Thank you. I have now reworked the whole thing. Things like `\section[contents entry for section \protect\textit{without} content]{section \protect\textit{without} content}` should not break any more. Sorry for the inconvenience. I don't know what I was thinking.

Answer (score 2):

Not completely robust but...

[image]

This version doesn't support `*` forms or optional arguments.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\makeatletter
\let\zzsection\section
\def\section#1{%
\@ifnextchar{\section}%
{\typeout{zap #1}\refstepcounter{section}}%
{\@ifnextchar{\par}{\zzparsection{#1}}{\zzsection{#1}}}%
}
\def\zzparsection#1\par{\section{#1}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{With content}

Bla, bla, ...

\section{No content}

\section{With content}

Bla, bla, ...

\section{With content}

Bla, bla, ...

\section{No content}

\section{With content}

Bla, bla, ...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Where have I to look for to understand all this magic ? :-)

Comment: @projetmbc `\@ifnextchar` is part of latex it just looks for the next thing (usually a character such as `[`  for seeing if there is an optional argument, but it can look for a command like `\section`) so if it sees `\par` (a blank line) it skips over that and tries again, if it sees `\section` then it discards the current section, and  otherwise it does the saved normal section definition.

Comment: Ok. One last question. What `typeout` does ?

Comment: @projetmbc  it just puts that text on the terminal and in the log file, put `\typeout{HELLO}` in any latex document, and you will see...

Comment: Cool. Thanks for all !